# Should we write unit tests for utilities? Or just write unit testings for use cases that refer to them?

Tags: unit-testing

Assume that we have a utility designed for checking date range validity (for example, start date not greater than end date, and maximum date range) and the utility is wildly used for all query APIs (about 40 APIs in total). The utility will generate 400 Bad Request if date range is invalid. Now the question is:

> We write unit tests for the utility so all unit tests for query APIs can assume that date range check works as expected.

versus

> Because query APIs are where use cases start, all unit tests for query APIs must include date range test cases to ensure that 400 Bad Request status will occur when date range is invalid.

Which one is proper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The philosophy behind the unit tests is to test the smallest testable peace of the software. From that point of view the answer is that you should test utility classes in order to create safety net around it and verify that the logic within the utility is valid.

On the other hand it depends also what is your QA strategy. I can imagine that you have QA gates where it is specified that for example business logic layer must be covered up to EX% but repository layer should not be covered at all. This is the valid real-life example where not everything is ideal :).

I would say that both approaches are valid. Let's say the public API is the bare minimum you should cover and ideally you should cover every testable peace of code.